# Non-www to www rewrite htaccess on shared hosting

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, shared-hosting

I have a shared hosting plan so my website is located in: /public_html/example.com/

The .htaccess is located in the root folder /public_html/

I want to redirect example.com to www.example.com

so far, I've used

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

When I use my browser on example.com/test/ it directs to www.example.com/example.com/test/

How can I fix that?

Comment: Do you have another rewrite that does a relative substitution and doesn't set RewriteBase?

Comment: hmm good point. I have one in /public_html/

`# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress`

Comment: Hrm unfortunately doesn't look like the culprit.

Comment: Should I have a different .htaccess in each of my shared-hosted websites? like in /public_html/example1/ and in /public_html/example2/ or should I only have one in the root directy in /public_html/ ?

Comment: Also, I tried deleting all .htaccess files in my directories including the original code that I showed in my question and the problem is still happening? O_O When I use my browser on example.com/test/ it directs to www.example.com/example.com/test/

Comment: Because this is a 301 redirect, you need to clear your cache each time you want to test.

Comment: I finally found a solution, even though it was not my preferred solution. I changed my domain as the main domain for my godaddy host plan (I moved it to /public_html/) and now everything is working like a charm...